# Soap request from browser triggers http preflight

Tags: javascript, xml, http, soap, preflight

### I want to call soap service from browser.

### Constraints

Only `POST` method is allowed and `Content-Type` should be `text/xml`

### Problem Statement:

The problem occurs when I change the `Content-Type` header to `text-xml`, browser triggers the pre-flight request (ie. request with `OPTIONS` method is triggered before the actual POST request)

If I remove the `Content-Type` then It gives `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

If `OPTIONS` method is triggered, it returns `405 Method Not Allowed`

What could be the possible solutions, keeping constraints in mind ?

Comment: Call the service from your server, if it doesn't support OPTIONS its not meant to be called from a browser

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So, there is no way to do it from browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the service from the server side, if it doesn't support OPTIONS its not meant to be called from a browser.